# Can I use open graph simply to obtain public facebook information?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use open graph to read story information off a public facebook page (http://www.facebook.com/onlinehorsesupplies). I want to obtain the message content of the latest post for use elsewhere on the related ecommerce website. I could scrape it but using open graph seems like it should be a better way to go.

Using the http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer I found the URL I need to use quite easily but I had to click on the 'get access token' to make it work. I use this URL:

https://graph.facebook.com/188288097875046?fields=posts&access_token=

If I use the access token copied off the explorer page it works fine. If I use an access token off my own app it fails with "Bad request...". How can I get an appropriate access token in my php code?

Answer (score 1):

I think your app needs to request a token first. At least thats how it worked for me.
Something like:

```
$app_token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret .
     "&grant_type=client_credentials";
$response = file_get_contents( $app_token_url );
parse_str( $response, $fbinfo );
```

then you can use that token for the request...

Comment: Thanks for your attempt. I think the facebook php api does this automatically. However the raw approach is probably fine for my needs and I've rephrased my question with what I've learned from your answer attempt

Comment: You are right, the php sdk does this automatically. I have looked at the sdk code and it gets its code from the following: 
`protected function getApplicationAccessToken() {
    return $this->appId.'|'.$this->appSecret;
  }`
what surprises me is that is not a dynamic token, like the one I use in my code to get a public page info. Maybe there is different levels of access. 
Maybe you could try, just for experimenmtation, to get the token with the code I posted, (explicitly requesting client credentials), and then using with the sdk, calling
`
`

Comment: sorry can't edit the previous comment anymore, anyways I meant: calling
`
$fbsdk-> setAccessToken($token);
`
before the graph call.

Comment: As per my edited question, the problem is that the app access token does not have the necessary access - even though the data is public and the token generated on the explorer page works fine.

Comment: ...and I did try your call both in the api and in the raw - same problem :(